# How to upload files to Google Drive from Web App

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I'm creating new feature in my web app.

I created google drive regular account. I want users to be able to see certain files
on that account and be able to add new files to this account.

I made authentication, I'm storing credentials and showing files (also deleting them) works fine. But I stumbled on a problem with uploading files. 
Every tutorial i saw , when it comes to acctual upload is doing something like :

```
$data = file_get_contents('document.txt');

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
      'data' => $data,
      'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    ));
```

But this works with file being on the server. As if user should first upload a file to my server , than my server should upload it do Google Drive.
Is there a way to upload a file through my Web App but directly from users PC?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a File input, and then submit it using the traditional methods. With that done, you can simply use `file_get_contents()` on the temp file.

For example, this may be your form:

```
<form action="drive_upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Then, your **`drive_upload.php`** will do this:

```
$data = file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);

$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
    'data' => $data,
    'mimeType' => 'text/plain',
    'uploadType' => 'media'
));
```

Note that I also took the liberty to add `uploadType` to the upload array. You'll also need a way to handle MIME types with this kind of upload, but that's a relatively straightforward process, and the above should get you started.